# What Spider-Man suits are in Peter Parker's secret hideout in Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse?

Tags: marvel, character-identification, spider-man, object-identification, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

In *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* (2018), Miles Morales, Peter B. Parker, and Gwen Stacy visit Aunt May’s home. She leads them to Peter Parker’s secret hideout, where they see several Spider-Man suits on display. **Are these suits based on different versions of Spider-Man from the comics or other media?**

The second suit from the right looks like it is the [Spider-Armor MK II](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Armor_MK_II) suit, and the second suit from the left looks like it is from [*Marvel’s Spider-Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(2018_video_game)) (2018), a video game developed by Insomniac Games. I’m curious if the rest of the suits are also based on Spider-Man suits from the comics or other related works.

Screencaps of the suits:

[image]
[image]

Caped suit, and blue suit with a protrusion on each shoulder:
[image: caped sui] [image: blue suit]

Other screencaps:
[image: caped suit] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Description of the suits (from left to right):

1. Red suit, no blue part, no visible web pattern
2. Suit that resembles the Insomniac Games [*Marvel’s Spider-Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(2018_video_game)) suit, with a prominent white spider emblem
3. Dark-blue suit with a protrusion on each shoulder, red spider emblem that resembles two rhombuses (diamond shape), red padding material on the arms and sides of the torso
4. Standard (?) Earth-616 suit
5. Dark blue-black suit with red web pattern and white spider emblem
6. Black suit, black lenses, no visible spider emblem or web pattern
7. Suit with a red cape
8. Black suit with neon green lenses and spider emblem
9. Suit with a mostly blue upper half, including a blue mask, and with a red lower half
10. Black and gray suit
11. Suit that is similar to the [Spider-Armor MK II](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Armor_MK_II) suit, with bright yellow lenses and spider emblem
12. Red suit with gold-colored lenses, forearms, and spider emblem

Comment: This gives some _Batman Beyond_ vibe.

Comment: The one with a cape looks like dr stranges costume, which spider man has worn before

Comment: Suit number 12 is almost definitely the [Iron Spider](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Iron_Spider_Armor), a gift from Iron-Man to Spider-Man with lots of electronic gadgets, from the beginning of Civil War in the comics

Comment: Suit number 2 looks like [the suit improved by Otto Octavius in 2018](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man%27s_Advanced_Suit)

Comment: Suit number 11 could be the [anti-Ock suit](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man%27s_Anti-Ock_Suit)

Comment: Suit number 3 could be the [Electro-proof suit](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man%27s_Electro-Proof_Suit)

Comment: Suit number 10 looks dark red and black to me, so it could be the [Superior Spider-Man suit](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Superior_Spider-Man's_Suit), used by Doc Ock when he was Peter Parker. It also looks more shiny than the other suits, so it could be the [Programmable Matter suit](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man%27s_Programmable_Matter_Suit) used by Miles Morales

Answer (score 10):

1. [The Spider](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-15))'s suit from *[Exiles Vol. 1 #12](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Exiles_Vol_1_12)* (June, 2002)
2. [Spider-Man's Advanced Suit](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man%27s_Advanced_Suit) from *[Marvel's Spider-Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel%27s_Spider-Man_(video_game))* (September, 2018)
3. [Spider-Man's Electro-Proof Suit](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man%27s_Electro-Proof_Suit) from *[Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 1 #42](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_425)5* (August, 1997)
4. [Spider-Man's Suit](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man%27s_Suit) from *[Amazing Fantasy Vol. 1 #15](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Fantasy_Vol_1_15)* (August, 1962)
5. [Secret War Suit](https://marvels-spider-man.fandom.com/wiki/Secret_War_Suit) from *[Secret War Vol. 1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Secret_War_Vol_1)* (2004–2005)
6. [Dusk's Suit](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Dusk%27s_Suit) from *[Spider-Man Vol. 1 #90](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man_Vol_1_90)* (April, 1998)
7. [Peter Parker (Earth-80219)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-80219))'s suit from *[What If? Vol. 1 #19](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/What_If%3F_Vol_1_19)* (February, 1980)
8. [Spider-Man's Stealth Suit](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man%27s_Stealth_Suit) from *[Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 1 #650](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_650)* (February, 2011)
9. [Web-Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Web-Man_(Earth-57780))'s suit from *[Spidey Super Stories Vol. 1 #25](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spidey_Super_Stories_Vol_1_25)* (August, 1977)
10. [Spider-Armor MK I](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Armor_MK_I) from *[Web of Spider-Man Vol. 1 #100](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Web_of_Spider-Man_Vol_1_100)* (May, 1993)
11. [Spider-Armor MK II](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Armor_MK_II) from *[Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 1 #656](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_656)* (May, 2011)
12. [Iron Spider Armor](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Iron_Spider_Armor) from *[Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 1 #529](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_529)* (April, 2006)

Comment: Just listing the ones I'm confident of for now. I'll try to pin down the remaining four later, unless someone else beats me to it.

Comment: 9 reminds me of [Web-Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Web-Man_(Earth-57780))'s suit from _[Spidey Super Stories #25](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spidey_Super_Stories_Vol_1_25)_ (August, 1977).

Comment: 10 reminds me of the [Spider-Armor MK I](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Armor_MK_I) from _[Web of Spider-Man Vol. 1 #100](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Web_of_Spider-Man_Vol_1_100)_ (May, 1993).

Comment: 6 reminds me of [Dusk's Suit](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Dusk%27s_Suit) from _[Spider-Man Vol. 1 #90](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man_Vol_1_90)_ (April, 1998). Earth-616 Spidey wore the suit himself in the same issue and a few others.

Comment: As indicated in my previous comments, I'm the least confident about suits 6 and 9, but I've looked around, and those are the closest fits so far, so this list what I'm going with for now. I'll keep looking, though.

Comment: Note that 9 also resembles the way Spider-Man's standard suit looked when he was corrupted by [Mister Negative](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mister_Negative_(Earth-616)) (which inverted the colour scheme of his suit) in _[Dark Reign: Mister Negative Vol. 1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Reign:_Mister_Negative_Vol_1)_ (2009).